# Expectation of a absolute of centered RV is bounded by root of variance?

Tags: variance, expected-value

I've seen a claim that for a RV x where $E(X)=0$, it holds that $E(|X|)\le\sqrt{Var(X)}$. How can you prove this? (and maybe what is the intuition for this?) Thanks

Comment: It is the fact that mean absolute deviation about mean is less than or equal to standard deviation. Use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$ is concave thus from [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality)
:
$$
\mathbb E\left(\sqrt{X^2}\right) \leq \sqrt{\mathbb E(X^2)}
$$

And $\sqrt{X^2} = \vert X \vert$ and since $\mathbb E(X) = 0$, $\text{Var}(X)= \mathbb E(X^2)$

Comment: Thanks winperikle. While I understand the answer, I saw this statement as a "by the way" comment in a second year class, and lecturer said the students should prove it as a task. Could it be that there's a simpler way to prove it? (there's no way they could know Jensen's inequality)